# how to write an Event handler that displays text

Tags: javascript, html

I need to write and register an event handler that display a text on the console log when h1 is moused over but I cannot get the text to display.
This is my javascript code:

```js
var h1Element = document.getElementsByTagName("h1")[0];

h1Element.addEventListener("mouseover", mouse);

function mouse() {
  console.log("my text here");
}
```

```html
<h1>I am an h1</h1>
```

Comment: This looks like it works. There must be something else that is wrong...

Comment: Your code is good and working for me.

Comment: So what is the error in your developer console if that does not work? Maybe you have your console to set to filter out logs?

Comment: To see the message, you need to open developer tools. In most browsers using F12 or using context menu (right click) and inspect element. If you want to edit the page you need to use `h1Element.innerHTML = 'my text here';`

Comment: the error says that "there is no output after the mousemove event on h1 element"